# Regular expression for arabic and english and some limited special characters

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I need regular expression that detect

1- any english letter  or

2- any arabic letter or

3- both or

4- any number in between ( or start or end place dose not matter)

5-Maximum length can be 30.

and make sure it dose not have special characters **except** (they can appear any where)

@    ,       =    %    $       #    &      _

**My Solution:**
I use this regular expression:

```
    var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s@,=%$#&_\u0600-\u06FF]).{0,30}$/;
    var result = regex.test('happy- - - /*  */ % ! ~');
    console.log(result);//prints true and it should print false because of ! and other special characters not allowed
```

***The Problem***

My solution is not correct

*My References*
For arabic i use 
[check here # 13 in the list](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html)
[Second reference](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28112360/Validate-the-string-to-accept-only-Arabic-English-alphabet-and-number-using-regex.html)
[Third reference](http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=2373)

U+0600–U+06FF

https://jsfiddle.net/shareefhiasat/bdm99b1x/

Comment: You quantified a **dot**. Remove the dot.

Comment: Seems strange to use _English_ characters. Do you mean  _Latin_ instead ?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes i think its working why you did not post that simple answer , please do and i will accept. and for down vote ! y.

Comment: Isn't it a typo? I suggest that you should remove the post.

Comment: You used the **Arabic block** which range from 600-6FF. But, there are more Arabic blocks. `[\p{Block=Arabic}\p{Block=Arabic_Extended_A}\p{Block=Arabic_Mathematical_Alphabetic_Symbols}\p{Block=Arabic_Presentation_Forms_A}\p{Block=Arabic_Presentation_Forms_B}\p{Block=Arabic_Supplement}]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to quantify the group, not the dot.
Here is a regex for all Arabic (Unicode 9) characters.
Note that you've just included some English characters, did you mean *Latin* ?

`^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\s@,=%$#&_\u0600-\u06FF\u0750-\u077F\u08A0-\u08FF\uFB50-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFDFF\uFE70-\uFEFF]|(?:\uD802[\uDE60-\uDE9F]|\uD83B[\uDE00-\uDEFF])){0,30}$`

https://jsfiddle.net/pydbqxgb/

Expanded

```
 ^     
 (?:
      [a-zA-Z0-9\s@,=%$#&_\u0600-\u06FF\u0750-\u077F\u08A0-\u08FF\uFB50-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFDFF\uFE70-\uFEFF] 
   |  
      (?:
           \uD802 [\uDE60-\uDE9F] 
        |  \uD83B [\uDE00-\uDEFF] 
      )
 ){0,30}
 $
```

---

An alternative, this uses basic non-control (whitespace only) Latin.

`^(?:[\u0009-\u000D\u001C-\u007E\u0600-\u06FF\u0750-\u077F\u08A0-\u08FF\uFB50-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFDFF\uFE70-\uFEFF]|(?:\uD802[\uDE60-\uDE9F]|\uD83B[\uDE00-\uDEFF])){0,30}$`

https://jsfiddle.net/st60dyve/

Expanded

```
 ^     
 (?:
      [\u0009-\u000D\u001C-\u007E\u0600-\u06FF\u0750-\u077F\u08A0-\u08FF\uFB50-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFDFF\uFE70-\uFEFF] 
   |  
      (?:
           \uD802 [\uDE60-\uDE9F] 
        |  \uD83B [\uDE00-\uDEFF] 
      )
 ){0,30}
 $
```

Comment: i tried the js fiddle it dose not work for example `test sadfasf sfd sadfas  _` where are the special characters plus sorry but its long dont you think

Comment: Returns _true_ in my fiddle links. And, don't judge a regex by it's length, it's the content of it's character (see [175,000 word Dictionary](http://www.regexformat.com/Dnl/_Samples/_Ternary_Tool%20(Dictionary)/___txt/_ASCII_175,000_word_Mix_A-Z_Multi_Lined.txt))

Comment: Btw, `\u0009-\u000D\u001C-\u007E` this covers basic Latin and whitespace within. This includes all symbols, letter, numbers, etc..

Answer (score 0):

simply use this Regex for alpha numeric English, Arabic and without space with minimum 5 characters.

`[0-9a-zA-Z\u0600-\u06FF]`